# Jade nodejs "no tag prefix"

Tags: node.js, pug

The documentation for Jade mentions a "no tag prefix", but I can't find what it is.

This means, as I see it, just plain text with no wrapping tag.

Suggestions?

Comment: Yeah, I think it is a plain text without wrapping tag. Use `|` for this.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
b bold
| plain
```

outputs

```
<b>bold</b>plain
```

Comment: Out of curiosity, how would you represent a bold section within the middle of a paragraph?  The equivalent of <p>This section is normal, however <b>this section<b> was bold.</p>

Comment: @MrMowgli what's the problem with applying my answer in your case? Alternatively, if you find it ugly, you may use markdown in Jade.

Comment: I think your answer is fine for continuing after a tag element like bold, I was thinking about the case where the bold is within a sentence and not the leading tag.  It's also an easy fix, you simply indent the bold tag under it's parent.

Comment: You can either break with pipes, like the example above, or use interpolation with Jade tags:

`text text #[b(class: "myClass") text] text text.`